# Spring data MongoDB check if field contains text

Tags: java, regex, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have field in mongoDb collection "name" which contains:

```
"26.11.2018(2)"
```

I use regex expression for searching if any string contains in field "name":

```
String search = "11.2018(2)";
return Criteria.where("name").regex(search);
```

I got exception, that regular expression is wrong(because of ")"). Is there any other possibility for searching like this?

Comment: Try to escape the brackets: `String search = "\\(2\\)"`

Comment: Also escape the dot, as it's a special char in regex; `"11\\.2018\\(2\\)"`

Comment: thanks, that is working for "(2)", but what in case if i will be searching "11.2018(2)"? Is there any "constant" expression which will be working for both queries?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Is there any "constant" expression which will be working for both queries?"

Comment: I am looking for solution which will be searching any string in mongoDb field, sometimes that string is like "simpleString", but sometimes like "string(2)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the value that's used in the regex.

I can't test it now, but it's possible that it may work:

```
String search = "some pattern(a)12.";
pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(search), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
return Criteria.where("name").regex(pattern);
```

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html

Comment: Pattern.escape has private access. Instead we can use Pattern.quote